Cppcheck: Out of bounds access because "container is empty" but container is not empty
I have this simple test code that creates a vector of two elements and prints it's size, then prints the first element:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<double> arr {0, 0.1};
    cout << arr.size() << endl;
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
}

The code compiles and runs fine and outputs 2 then 0 as it should.
However when I run Cppcheck on this file it reports this:
error: Out of bounds access in expression 'arr[0]' because 'arr' is empty. [containerOutOfBounds]
 cout << arr[0] << endl;
            ^

But arr is clearly not empty!
Is this a false positive or am I missing something?
Running with Cppcheck version 2.12

Looks like a false positive. I am curious about two things: 1) what happens if you use vector<double> arr {0.0, 0.1};? 2) what happens if you use vector<double> arr(0, 0.1);?

I would say a false positive (looks like a parse error)

Can you try with vector<double> arr {42, 0.1};? Maybe cppcheck "uses" the wrong constructor.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

What @Jarod42 is getting at is that it is reasonable to theorize that cppcheck is treating the first number as the size. If that is the case, it (incorrectly) sees your code as creating a vector with zero elements, each initialized to 0.1, and it would (incorrectly) see vector<double> arr {42, 0.1}; as creating a vector with 42 elements, each initialized to 0.1. (I don't have cppcheck installed, so I cannot put this theory to the test myself.)

@PeteBecker: I consider those recommandations mostly as premature optimisation: the extra flush avoids lot of issues with beginners (as log is complete).

@Wutz the first one gives no errors and the second one reports the same thing as in my question but I think it is correct in both cases here

@Jarod42 I think that is the case here. This indeed looks like it confuses (0, 0.1) and {0, 0.1} initialization and assumes 0 is the size instead of an element

@MikhailKriseev thank you for checking my questions. I was getting at the same thing others already said - cppcheck assumes the wrong ctor. Making the first parameter a double (question 1) makes cppcheck realize which ctor is being used.

Upstream issue created: https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/12738#ticket

This seems to be another cppcheck bug/defect. There was similar issue some years ago.
Here is the old issue:
Out of bounds access in expression 'test_array[0]' because 'test_array' is empty.

The issue has been fixed in the upcoming Cppcheck 2.15: https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/12738.
